# Looking for a Bitcoin Cash (bch, bcc) testnet faucet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, faucets

As the title states I am looking for a Bitcoin Cash faucet. I know about the very nice one:

https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/bitcoin-cash-faucet

but it seems to be down at the moment. A google search does not yield any other faucets so I am not very optimistic.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BCH ABC testnet Faucet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81275/bch-abc-testnet-faucet)

Answer (score 4):

There's a new faucet, it can be accessed here: https://testnet.wormhole.cash/faucet/

Edit: Broken! Coinfaucet still works.

Comment: Death atm. not working any more!

Answer (score 2):

https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/bitcoin-cash-faucet
worked for me. Please try again and report back.

Comment: No, its not working atm

Comment: True. Now it is 4 month later, and the site actually offline due to spam issues on the testnet.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this one that seems to work:
https://coinfaucet.eu/en/bch-testnet/

Answer (score 0):

There is an active faucet for Bitcoin Cash (BCH) testnet coins at:

https://tbch.googol.cash

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, https://tbch.googol.cash does not appear to be working (after entering address and number gives 500 error back)

Comment: @user134281 can you test again? seems working now.