# Bitcoin cash faucet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, faucets

Is there any other bitcoin cash faucet instead of [this](https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/bitcoin-cash-faucet)

I'm facing the same problem as [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75622/looking-for-a-bitcoin-cash-bch-bcc-testnet-faucet) question.

Comment: are you looking for BCH faucet or some BCH-testnet coins?

Comment: I believe OP looking for BCH-testnet coins.

Comment: I am looking for working 'BCH faucet', wanna test my BCH wallet web hook (test.bitgo.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this site for getting Testnet coins:

https://testnet.coinfaucet.eu/en/

Comment: Bitcoin "Cash"...

Comment: I am NOT looking for bitcoin faucet. I am looking for BCH ->  bitcoin cash faucet