# BCH ABC testnet Faucet?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-cash, testnet, faucets, ecash

I want a bitcoin cash ABC chain (BCHABC) testnet faucet.
Cause 15th Nov. onwards after a hard fork on bitcoin cash network existing bch faucets are not working. Even questions over here are also not upto the mark https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=faucet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is started working now. 
I guess after stabilizing ABC chain it is started working as expected tried with https://testnet.wormhole.cash/faucet/

https://coinfaucet.eu/en/bch-testnet/
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this is a faucet that's up these days: https://faucet.fabien.cash/

At least the only testnet explorer for ABC that I've found so far is https://texplorer.bitcoinabc.org/ (data for mainnet seems to be the same as other explorers show: https://blockchair.com/ecash , https://ecashexplorer.com). But I can't fully confirm it's working correctly since I haven't found yet how to generate address from mnemonic for XEC ([haven't found derivation path yet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113037/128964)) and can't really test it (and testnet explorer doesn't show many addresses: all the latest txs are sending from address A to address B which both don't work with the faucet until waiting for 24 hours).